# GUI in Python 3 using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple GUI as part of my learning Python/Tkinter - trying to get a save button to work, but am getting the error: TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entries'

Internet research doesn't help me, have been trying all day!

Thanks for any help in advance, my full code is below:

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

fields = 'Owners Name', 'Rate', 'length', 'Length_of_stay'

def save(entries):
text_file = open ("text.txt","a") 
text_file.write (entries)
entries = []
    for entry in entries:
   field = entry[0]
   text = entry[1].get() + "\n"
with open("text.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(entries)

def fetch(entries):
   for entry in entries:
  field = entry[0]
  text  = entry[1].get()
  print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text)) 

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = []
   for field in fields:
  row = Frame(root)
  lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
  ent = Entry(row)
  row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
  lab.pack(side=LEFT)
  ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
  entries.append((field, ent))
   return entries


def onSave(entries):   #save command
    filename = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt')
    if filename:
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(entries.gettext())

def calc(entries):
x = (int(entries['Rate'].get()))
y = (int(entries['length'].get()))
z = x + y
print(z)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   w = Label(text="Cardiff Yachting Marina Booking System")
   w.pack()
   w = Label(text="Hourly: £0.50\nDaily: £10.00\nWeekly:£50.00\nMonthly: £180.00\nYearly: £1320.50\n", justify=LEFT)
   w.pack()
   w = Label(text="Complete your booking details below:")
   w.pack()
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
   b1 = Button(root, text='Show',
      command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
   b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b3 = Button(root, text='Calculate',
    command=(lambda e=ents: calc(e)))
   b3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b = Button(root, text="save", width=9, command=save)
   b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the save function as a callback, no Arguments are passed to it.

Either declare a global variable for it or think of a way to pass them into the callback.

Also please check your indent of lines when posting code samples on SO.